# Regexp to CSS file

Tags: css, regex

I need to add [New LINE] in CSS compressed file using Notepad++ search regexp

my code like this:

```
html{direction:ltr;overflow-x:hidden}body,textarea,input,select{font:normal 12px/18px "arial";text-align:left.....
```

I need to replace: `html{}body{}` OR `.html{}.body{}` TO:

```
html{}
body{}
```

I think i can use this

`/}*` Repace: ENTER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do in Notepad++ is to search for `}` and replace it with `}\n`. Make sure that your cursor is at the beginning of the first line. This will make sure that all occurances are replaced.